How to buy tickets for Super Nintendo World Osaka?
I would like to buy 5 tickets for Super Nintendo World in Osaka Japan. The most straightforward way I think would be by buying them at the Universal Studios Japan site, Unfortunately, you can only buy up to 4 tickets for Adults at the same time. Why is that?
So if I'm correct I need to buy tickets from a Travel Agency like klook. Now it is becoming more unclear to me. On the website, they say:

Immerse yourself with thrills the whole family can enjoy at SUPER
NINTENDO WORLD™! Secure your entry with the Area Timed Entry Ticket &
Studio Pass combo ticket!

Does this mean that you can only enter Super Nintendo World in a certain time slot or does this count for the complete Universal Studios?
Assuming I need the [SUPER NINTENDO WORLD] + 1 Day Studio Pass, The following is included:

1 【E-ticket】Universal Studios Japan 1 Day Pass ticket(s)
The Area Timed Entry Ticket: Super Nintendo World™ (Entry to the area)
Please select admission time to Super Nintendo World™ when booking

And the following is not included:

Express pass, additional expense for chargable attractions

So does this mean that you can get in the Nintendo world for certain time? Also you may obtain an express pass but I can't find where you can buy that one. To be honest I find it really unclear what all the tickets mean and their differences. If someone could explain me how you can just buy 5 tickets for Super Nintendo World (without) a time slot? It would really help me if this was a little clearer.

The reason they limit them is to prevent re-sellers, its a pity they don't account for the fact that some people generally come in large groups

Ticketing for Universal Studios Japan is indeed a mess.  The Wikivoyage page tries to explain it, but the TL;DR version:

Super Nintendo World is within USJ, so you need to get a USJ day ticket ("Studio Pass") first.
Access to Super Nintendo World is only by assigned time slot.  There are three ways to get these:

Buy a combo ticket like the one you're seeing on Klook.  Convenient but costs more.
Download the official app and try to book a timed entry slot. Free, and you can choose any time that suits you if available, but they fill up fast.
Buy a separate Express Pass that comes with a guaranteed entry slot, but at a randomly assigned time (no changes allowed).  If you get multiple Express Passes, the randomly assigned times will probably be different. Some Express Passes include express entry to the Mario Kart ride, which otherwise will usually require 1-2 hours of queuing.


The assigned time is for entry, once in you can stay as long as you like.  However, the area is not very big and only has two rides, even the most hardcore Mario fan will run out of things to do in a few hours.


Thank you very much for your clear answer! It is indeed a mess. I bought some tickets, hopefully it is right.
